# Анимация текста jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как реализовать это условие. Подскажите:
Заголовок красного цвета движется слева направо, уменьшается и
увеличивается по 2 раза соответственно, пока не дойдет до правого края

Answer (score 3):

```css
@keyframes anime {
  12.5% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
  37.5% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  62.5% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
  87.5% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: calc(100% - 300px);
  }
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  color: red;
  animation: anime 3s linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<h2>Заголовок красного цвета</h2>
```

Можно и без `jQuery` на чистом `CSS`.

Comment: Спасибо, но задача именно использовать JQuery